# Minimum device requirements to enroll in the Apple Developer Program as an Organisation

Tags: developer-program

What are the minimum device requirements to enroll in the Apple Developer Program as organization?

We have an iPhone 6 and a MacBook Pro (mid 2012). The iPhone 6 runs iOS 12.4.9 and the MacBook Pro runs macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

We already have DUNS number and we meet all the requirements for Apple's registration as an organisation.

Comment: I have replied with the minimum device requirements for enrollment. However, it seems like you have left out some important parts of your story. I would suggest opening a new question with the actual, specific "roadblocks" you have found. I.e. do you get an error message or what exactly happens. Enrolling in the Apple Developer Program as an organization is usually something that can be done in a matter of a day or two - not something that takes years as your question seemed to indicate.

Comment: @jksoegaard last 2 years apple provide us 6 or 7 representative and 3 times remotely access our MacBook Pro and we couldn't finalise the enrolment for our organization. Even with their suggesting we created 2 different Apple ID. But last 4 weeks in 2 attempt we got mail  stated that our organisation is in a country that is not supported from Apple. :( Its a very and painful process. I and my friend can enrol as individual but we can't enrol our company.

Comment: Which country are you in? ... Enrolling an organisation takes a day or two - if you have waited for multiple years, you're doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

There's no minimum device requirements as such to enroll in the Apple developer program - all you need is 2-factor authentication enabled on your Apple-ID. Your iPhone 6 and MacBook Pro is able to support that without problems.

Comment: already 2-factor authentication enabled on our Apple-ID. But last 2 years they were expecting news from internal team and they suggest 3 different scenario and now we got mail stated that our organisation is in a country that is not supported from Apple. :(